# If a POD is wrapped inside a class, does it give the same effect?

Tags: c++, class, wrapper

Following are 2 different interpretations:

```
char c;  // 1
struct MyChar { char c; };  // 2
```

If I do `new MyChar[100]`, will it allocate 100 bytes in all platform ? Adding non-`virtual` constructor/destructor and/or `operator`s will make any effect on the size of `MyChar` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MyChar` may have unnamed padding bytes after `c`, so no, it isn't guaranteed that `sizeof(MyChar)` is `1`.

Comment: Is there any standard language support to avoid that padding ?

Comment: Nope; your only option is really to use compiler-specific structure packing pragmas/attributes.

Comment: Many common compilers use `#pragma pack (1)`... GCC, IBM, MS... how best to restore the default packing afterwards might be a bit more variable though, can't remember :-).

Answer (score 2):

On MSVC, you can use:

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct MyChar 
{ 
    char c; 
}; 

// Restore
#pragma pack()
```

Comment: Are you sure?  I'm almost certain that you need to use `#pragma pack(push) / #pragma pack(1)` followed after use by `#pragma pack(pop)`.  It is my understanding that the `#pragma pack()` sets the pack value back to its default, whatever that is, which may not be what the packing was before your `#pragma pack(1)`.

Comment: `push` and `pop` are used to stack-up the pragmas packs. They aren't necessary. For example your packing may be 2 and then 4 and then 1, there you may use `push/pop`. I have used `pack(1)` and then reverted using `pack()` and works as needed.